# Tracking dbus 'connection' between server/client

Tags: dbus

The notion of a dbus connection tracks the connection between a given server/client to the dbus daemon (is this correct?).

Is there a way to track a higher level, 'connection/session' between a given server and client pair for a set of interactions they may have each other?

Use-case: I have a set of APIs that my server exposes that require a client to register itself to the server first, before engaging in interactions with the server. The server in turn calls a number of methods on an object registered by the client. In this regard, the server is stateful, and has to track some salient details about the client. The set of methods exposed by both involve a mix of ones that have replies, and ones that don't.

My thinking: By having a centralized place that handles all 'session' failures between the two, it makes it easier to handle errors that may happen between the two, including cases where either crashes/restarts without having sent messages between each other.

FYI: I'm using libdbus.

Answer (score 0):

No, the D-Bus protocol does not provide features for this; you have to implement it yourself.

The typical architecture to use for this kind of problem is to have your client process expose an object implementing a well-known interface to the bus, and then pass the object path of that object to the server by calling a `Register()` (or similarly named) method on the server.

Both the client and server processes should watch for [`NameOwnerChanged` signals](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#bus-messages-name-owner-changed) to see if the other has disappeared off the bus.

Finally, I recommend not using libdbus, as its API is hard to use correctly. A more modern, high-level API such as [`GDBus`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gdbus-convenience.html) would be easier to use correctly.

Comment: Ah interesting! How does that work if the dbus daemon itself disappeared/crashed?

Comment: If the dbus-daemon itself disappears, you will need to recover everything. However, you should probably not design for that situation. The dbus-daemon should never crash. If it does, you have much bigger problems (the rest of the system likely won’t recover).